# How to shrink possible types?

Tags: typescript

I have the Map, with next  combinations:

```
type MAP = Map<string|symbol, object|symbol>;
```

But, it's possible to have only three of combinations:

```
type MAP = Map<string, object> ;
type MAP = Map<symbol, object> ;
type MAP = Map<string, symbol> ;
```

And it's not possible to have

`type MAP = Map<symbol, symbol> ;`

How can i describe this?

Comment: No. It describes 3 different Maps, but not different pairs of <K,V>

Answer (score 0):

You can make `MAP` a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) instead of the type arguments to `Map` to do this:

```
type MAP = Map<string, object>
         | Map<symbol, object>
         | Map<string, symbol>;
```

Now anytime you have a value of type `MAP` it can be either a `Map<string, object>`, a `Map<symbol, object>` or a `Map<string, symbol>`.

---

However, as soon as you start using a value of type `MAP`, as opposed to one of the 3 `Map<K, V>` types, there's no way to guess which one of these types you're dealing with. You would have to come up with runtime checks to assert the actual type, for example, to test whether a value of type `MAP` is a `Map<string, object>`:

```
function isStringObjectMap(map: MAP): map is Map<string, object> {
    // Assert that keys are strings & values are objects...
}
```

So it depends on your use-case how useful the `MAP` type really is.

Comment: I've tried the suggestion. But i've got 
```map.get(id)  ```

TS2345: Argument of type 'Symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & Symbol'.   Type 'Symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Did you try to assign to a variable of type `string & symbol`? Because that will always fail. There's no value that is a `string` and `symbol` at the same time. This also demonstrates what I tried to explain about the 'usefulness' of the MAP type; you must first assert what type of MAP you're dealing with before you can know what type `id` must be before calling `map.get(id)`, and before you can know what type `map.get(id)` will then return.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but if you want one map where you can have the three combinations of `K, V` simultaneously, you're out of luck I'm afraid, because the `Map` type provides no way to 'whitelist' value types based on a given type of key.

Comment: Yep. That is a problem. Your suggestion defines the 3 types of map, but not 3 possible combinations of <K,V>.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that by having different arguments at the level of `MAP` type. In order to group two elements the simplest way is to pass arguments in pairs. Consider:

```
type MAP<Inside extends [string, object] | [symbol, object] | [string, symbol]> 
= Map<Inside[0], Inside[1]>;

// using
type MyMapCorrect = MAP<[string, symbol]> // ok
type MyMapError = MAP<[symbol, symbol]> // error as it should
```

Type `MAP` clearly defines allowed pairs, other combinations are not allowed.

---

Second solution is conditional type:

```
type MAP<First extends string | symbol
, Second extends (First extends string ? object | symbol : object)> 
= Map<First, Second>;
// using
type MyMapCorrect = MAP<string, symbol> // ok
type MyMapError = MAP<symbol, symbol> // error as it should
```

We define relation between first argument and the second. The benefit of this approach is no introduction of the additional tuple, but code is more complicated, therefor I prefer the first solution.

[The Playground for both solutions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABBYPRWDEBGMBxATgewK4AcCWA7AczALGwENdUBncSAFwE9sBTMAWQEEAFAHgEl81XABM2LAB70W%20EdTABtavVQFCAGjDoARgCsWAY3oBdMAB9F1RgFtt6ADaad%20o6YtKVazVdsPjAPjAAXg5ybAEhURYFAAZjTUFhMQUEAIBuEDoIGDBMYSIssCZWDkZ2MIBhdFRUQ3pgjh5eD1Uibxs7ewDoWHQAa0LitnYysIBRGuqGrj4lDod23y7AnJZJ1DByeVx66gALLHsREABfEFBIHvgAJjAq2R3cdHxyeyLmFkGPxr4AMSplGBJNJZPJlK1iBYfJ1NABlQzPERAqQyORgAAU-xo9WBqLBniIYAA-Fo9HVzGBoQ4wAAuUkuegASkCIXK4SxyjhCNk-gylxyeTUXxKIzZVRq5NZTXBXkp83sK16A0uQ1KbImGA2Ur4VMccqWiqB602212B0wR1OmSAA)